# Connecting Arduino to GPS Chip with Single Pin

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, wiring, gps

I was given an old Garmin GPS unit from a friend and decided to tinker around with it and see if I could connect the GPS chip up to my Arduino to use with their GPS library.  Problem is, the chip itself has a single pin coming off of it and I'm not sure what to do with it.  I've definitely worked with temperature sensors that are a single pin... Is this a common type of connection and if so - could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can hook this up to power it and send / receive data?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

That's not a GPS reciever, just an antenna. If you've got the rest of the reciever there you might be able to get NMEA out of it somewhere, but the antenna on its own is not something you can easilty make use of.